# Finding all large files in the root filesystem

Tags: find, disk-usage

I have a linux server, which currently has below space usage:

```
/dev/sda3              20G   15G  4.2G  78% /
/dev/sda6              68G   42G   23G  65% /u01
/dev/sda2              30G  7.4G   21G  27% /opt
/dev/sda1              99M   19M   76M  20% /boot
tmpfs                  48G  8.2G   39G  18% /dev/shm
```

As you can see. `/` is at 78%. I want to check, which files or folders are consuming space.

I tried this:

```
find . -type d -size +100M
```

Which shows result like this:

```
./u01/app/june01.dbf
./u01/app/temp01.dbf
./u01/app/smprd501.dbf
./home/abhishek/centos.iso
./home/abhishek/filegroup128.jar
```

Now this is my issue. I only want the name of those files located in folders that are consuming space at `/` and not at `/u01` or `/home`. Since `/` is base of everything, it is showing me every file of my server.

Is is possible to get big files that is contributing to 78% of `/` ?

Comment: See the `-xdev` find predicate. See also `du -kx / | xdu` (or `xdiskusage`).

Comment: See also [my answer to a related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140319/15241).

Comment: relevant `find . -type f -print | xargs du -sk | sort -rn`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522269/bash-how-to-find-the-largest-file-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Try:

```
find / -xdev -type f -size +100M
```

It lists all files that has size bigger than 100M.

If you want to know about directory, you can try `ncdu`.

If you aren't running Linux, you may need to use `-size +204800` or `-size +104857600c`, as the `M` suffix to mean megabytes isn't in POSIX.

```
find / -xdev -type f -size +102400000c
```

Comment: `-xdev` just prevents find from walking across filesystems, so you'll only search your current physical drive. If that's not what you want, just remove the `-xdev` arg.

Comment: i was just wondering. Should be this command run without sudo (on `/`) ? Without sudo it produces a LOT of warnings, rendering the output unreadable

Comment: @user1762087 You can use `sudo` if you don't have permission.

Comment: what do you mean by `ncdu` for directory? How to search for directories?

Answer (score 67):

The following command not only find you the top 50 largest files (>100M) on your filesystem, but also sort (GNU `sort`) by the biggest:

```
find / -xdev -type f -size +100M -exec du -sh {} ';' | sort -rh | head -n50
```

> `-xdev` Don't descend directories on other filesystems.
>
> <sup>On BSD `find` use `-x` which is equivalent to the deprecated `-xdev` primary.</sup>

For all files and directories, it's even easier:

```
du -ahx / | sort -rh | head -20
```

(the `-x` flag is what's required to constrain `du` to a single filesystem)

If you're not using GNU `sort` (from `coreutils`), use it without `-h`:

```
du -ax / | sort -rn | head -20
```

For current directory only (for quicker results), replace `/` with `.`.

Comment: I would mention that this method is good because `-h` shows human readable output, and add a sample output.

Comment: Very good solution. Thank you.

Comment: how to make ```du``` show only files not directories?

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 57):

In addition to @Gnouc answer, you can also use the `exec` option of `find` combined with `ls -la` to get more details. You should have `sudo` privileges to do that.

```
$ find / -xdev -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lha {} \; | sort -nk 5
```

To only see files that are in the gigbyte, do:

```
root# du -ahx / | grep -E '\d+G\s+'

1.8G    /.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A960D58E-A644-4497-B3C1-866A529BF919
1.8G    /.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2
```